# A nicer way to handle Properties Changes in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm building a MVVM application in which a `ToBeListened` class has a couple of properties, `PropertyA` and `PropertyB`, and I want to listen to them.

```
public class ToBeListened : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private double _propertyA;
    private string _propertyB;
    /*Here I'm omitting the update part where NotifyPropertyChanged gets called*/
    public double PropertyA{get; set; }
    public double PropertyB{get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Those two properties are listened by a `Listener` class, so I've implemented an EventHandler in it, that listens to a `ToBeListened` object.

```
public class Listener
{

     private ToBeListened toBeListenedObject; 

     public Listener()
     {  
        toBeListenedObject = new ToBeListened();
        toBeListenedObject.PropertyChanged += newPropertyChangedEventHandler(PropertyListener_PropertyChanged);
     }

     private void PropertyListener_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
     {
        switch(e.PropertyName)
        {
          case "PropertyA":
          {
            /*...DO SOMETHING...*/
          }
          case "PropertyB":
          {
            /*...Do something else...*/
          }
    }
```

The thing is, I don't really like this solution I've found. A `switch-case` isn't polymorphism-friendly, so

1. is there a better way to do this? Maybe something that uses **overloading**? (Like `private void PropertyListener_PropertyChanged(double sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)`
2. most of all, is it right to code a ViewModel like this?

Comment: Why not have a PropertAChanged event, and a PropertyBChanged event?

Comment: Doesn't `toBeListenedObject.PropertyChanged` handle one `EventHandler` at the time?

Comment: Minor note: in recent versions of C#, you can use `nameof(ToBeListened.PropertyA)` in place of `"PropertyA"`; I'm not saying that the approach is a good idea, though

Comment: @RowlandShaw because that *isn't the `INotifyPropertyChanged` signature*? also: it will require either lazy event management (there is a common pattern for this via `EventHandlerList`, but it isn't trivial), or lots of overhead of usually-null  delegate references

Comment: @MarcGravell No, it isn't; but if the consumer of the class has a good reason to need to know about a specific property changed, then there's reason to do it (or better still, define a domain specific interface that defines it) - of course, this is how all the WinForms controls handle it, albeit pre-dating INotifyPropertyChanged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the past I've used a little class derived from `Dictionary<string, Action>` for this purpose. It was something like this:

```
public class PropertyChangedHandler : Dictionary<string, Action>
{
    public PropertyChangedHandler(INotifyPropertyChanged source)
    {
        source.PropertyChanged += Source_PropertyChanged;
    }

    private void Source_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Action toDo;
        if (TryGetValue(e.PropertyName, out toDo))
        {
            toDo();
        }
    }
}
```

Then your listener looks like this:

```
public class Listener
{
    private ToBeListened toBeListenedObject = new ToBeListened();

    PropertyChangedHandler handler;

    public Listener()
    {
        handler = new PropertyChangedHandler(toBeListenedObject)
                    {
                        { "PropertyA", DoA },
                        { "PropertyB", DoB }
                    };
    }

    private void DoB()
    {            
    }

    private void DoA()
    {            
    }
}
```

This is just an example to give you an idea - it can be expanded for more complex purposes, of course.

Comment: What does `out ToDo` do in this case?

Comment: It passes a reference to the `ToDo` variable to the `TryGetValue` function, and mandates that it be set to some value when the function returns. The result here is that `ToDo` becomes the required `Action` if it's in the dictionary, and `null` otherwise.

Comment: Thanks. This method suited my project better.

Answer (score 4):

I like Josh Smith's PropertyObserver, which you can get at http://mvvmfoundation.codeplex.com/ (some documentation from Josh at https://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2009/07/11/one-way-to-avoid-messy-propertychanged-event-handling/). It's a nice class that encapsulates the plumbing logic you're talking about, so you can focus on just handling changes to certain properties. So in your case, you could write code like:

```
var observer = new PropertyObserver<ToBeListened>(toBeListenedObject)
                  .RegisterHandler(tbl => tbl.PropertyA, tbl => HandlePropertyA(tbl))
                  .RegisterHandler(tbl => tbl.PropertyB, tbl => HandlePropertyB(tbl));
```

You can start using it by installing the MVVM Foundation nuget package into your solution. The ID is MvvmFoundation.Wpf.

Comment: I like this! Is there something similar that works with an UWP app? It isn't supported unfortunately. (I know I've forgot to write it in the OP, I apologize)

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a good answer for UWP. Like you say, it's not supported due to the lack of weak reference events in UWP. I think the source code for this class could be a great starting point though if you wanted to refactor for a slightly different approach and write your own UWP PropertyObserver. Other than that, I don't have any great ideas. Maybe Fody or PostSharp could inject custom events for each property that you could use? There's not a ready-to-use UWP solution out there as far as I know.

Comment: Sorry if I've marked you answer as correct before testing it. I've tried @Baldrick method and it suits my project best. Thanks for the input though.

Answer (score 0):

i think MVVM Light framework (or library?) has what you need. Take a look at their `ObservableObject` class http://www.mvvmlight.net/help/SL5/html/d457231f-6af7-601d-fa1f-1fe7c9f60c57.htm

Basically what it does, is making your object observable.